# Cannot destructure property 'version' of 'this.$projectDataService.getRuntimePackage(...)' as it is undefined. NativeScript 7 + Angular 10

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

App after upgrade NativeScript to v7 and Angular to v10, works perfect when building in debug mode - on emulator and on real iOS device. But when pushing app to TestFlight it is Crashing just after run. So I tried to run on emulator in release mode:

tns run ios --release --clean --emulator

And just after searching for devices I see an error:

Cannot destructure property 'version' of 'this.$projectDataService.getRuntimePackage(...)' as it is undefined.

tns run ios (without release parameter) works, app builded and working well on emulator.